# Is there anyway to stop scrolling programmatically?

Tags: javascript, iscroll

This is disabling all scroll functionality.

```
var myScroller = new IScroll('#wrapper');
myScroller.disable();
```

Is there any way to stop scrolling(not disable iscroll)?

```
var myScroller = new IScroller('#wrapper');
myScroller.stopScroll() ?
myScroller.preventScroll() ?
myScroller.stayFixed() ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading [the documentation](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)? Don't just try to guess the name of a function. Perhaps [this](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll#optionsdisablemouseoptionsdisablepointeroptionsdisabletouch) will help you:

> options.disableMouse
>   options.disablePointer
>   options.disableTouch
>
> By default iScroll listens to all pointer events and reacts to the
>   first one that occurs. It may seem a waste of resources but feature
>   detection has proven quite unreliable and this listen-to-all approach
>   is our safest bet for wide browser/device compatibility.
>
> If you have an internal mechanism for device detection or you know in
>   advance where your script will run on, you may want to disable all
>   event sets you don't need (mouse, pointer or touch events).

---

IScroll isn't designed to *prevent* scrolling, so if that's what you're using it for, ditch it. Even if you still want IScroll for when scrolling is enabled, perhaps this could help you: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I have already initiate IScroll and got instance 'myScroller', what I mean is how to disable scroll movement by using this 'myScroll' instance. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Kim Well IScroll isn't designed to _prevent_ scrolling. Was that the only reason you used IScroll?

Comment: Actually, there are [modal/mask](https://github.com/jsor/lity) show up dynamically on this scroll div. I want to prevent scroll movement when modal/mask is opened. Maybe I should work on how to prevent touch through event(when modal is open) other than prevent IScroll scroll movement. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @Kim What most people do when creating a modal popup is to also create an invisible (or sometimes partially-visible) overlay over the whole page but behind the popup. That way clicks and other events can be eaten up by the overlay.